# Variables in Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, routes

I have searched and tried many different things mentioned in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html but none seam to do what I want.

The Gist: 
I have a controller that sets up views for different phone types

```
class PhoneViewsController < ApplicationController
  def android_automated
    #Do Android Stuff
  end
  def android_interactive
    #Do Android Stuff
  end
  def ios_automated
    #Do Apple Stuff
  end
  def ios_interactive
    #Do Apple Stuff
  end
  def blackberry_automated
    #Do Blackberry Stuff
  end
  def blackberry_interactive
    #Do Blackberry Stuff
  end
end
```

Each method above has a corresponding view partial in the phone_views view folder

I want to have urls like /android/interactive be read as phone_views#android_interactive

Rails routes has syntax that lets me redirect with parameters such as

```
 get 'android/:action', to: redirect('/phone_views/android_%{action}')
 get 'phone_views/:action' , :controller => 'phone_views'
```

This renders the correct page but has the nasty side effect of a funky url

I have tried taking this and using it as:

```
get 'android/:mode', :to => 'phone_views#android_%{mode}'
```

but I get an action %{mode} not found error as though it didn't see %{mode} as a variable

```
get 'android/:action', :controller => 'phone_views', :action => 'android_%{action}'
```

results in a error action "interactive" not found and:

```
get 'android/:mode', :controller => 'phone_views', :action => 'android_%{mode}'
```

get the same action %{mode} not found error as above.

What is the syntax for taking a named variable such as :mode in the get request and using it in forming the action?

Update: 
I believe I almost figured this out. The variables don't seem to be accessible in the manner that I was trying to use them but if you pass the request to a proc{} they seem to be accessible.

```
match 'android/:mode', to: proc{|params| action = params['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters'][:mode]; control = PhoneViewsController.new(); control.send('android_' + action)}, via: [:get]
```

This however only results in an error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass but the error is in the appropriate controller. Hope this helps solve this.

Comment: have you tried simple  `get 'android/interactive', :to => 'phone_views#android_interactive'`?

Comment: Yes and that does work however, it means that I have to make an entry for every possible android mode. Where if I can just figure out the syntax for accessing the variable I could make this approach more dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want to give a random internet user the ability to choose whatever controller method they feel like accessing, so this is what you should do:

```
[:automated, :interactive].each do |mode|
  [:android, :ios, :blackberry].each do |device|
    get "#{ device }/#{ mode }", :to => "phone_views##{ device }_#{ mode }"
  end
end
```

If you need to add another device or mode, you just need to update your routes.rb file after you've completed the methods in the controller/views/etc.

If you really wanted to get fancy, you can move these static symbol arrays into their own class for managing devices and the modes they support.

Also, make sure you put constraints on your inputs when dealing with colon variables in routes.

EDIT: Extra " at the end of the `get` call was removed

Comment: Great job, this does work (after I took out the extra quote on line 3) and you even thought about security. Can you add a link to a source that describes this solution (why it works) so that I can give you the bounty?

Comment: It works because it's basic Ruby code. You iterate through the modes array, and for each of those modes you iterate through devices. For every one of those combinations, you make a call to the `get` method and supply it with the strings from those two arrays. With regards to the string itself, the #{} syntax is a part of Ruby's string interpolation. http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex6.html

Comment: I'll award the bounty but was looking for a reference to this being used in routes.rb or something that says this is allowed in routes.rb since while simple ruby syntax it required the use of string replacement in the search string and an escape sequence in the controller/action string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `%` when you should be using `#`.  This works for me:

```
get 'android/:mode', :to => 'phone_views#android_#{mode}'
```

Comment: Error android_ could not be found for controller phone_views. It sees the # sign and thinks it's another param like an ID

Comment: This morning I looked again and noticed you were using string literal I changed to double quotes and got a different error message: undefined local variable or method `mode' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:GUID> At least it recognizes it as a variable now. But wonder why it would be undefined since the url was android/interactive?

Comment: You should be using single quotes, otherwise it will try to use the mode variable when the routes are loaded instead of at run time.

Comment: single quotes lead to the error mentioned in my first comment. I am speculating but it appears to see the # and ignore the rest of the statement.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails 4.0.3 ruby 2.1.2p95

Comment: The problem with this, is that `mode` isn't actually a variable. When you see `:mode`, that's just a string. That string is eventually used by the router in a unique way (probably regex) when routing incoming requests to controllers and their methods. When the routes.rb file is read in by the route generator, it tries to insert a variable called `mode` into the string...and `mode` isn't a variable that's been set anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think why your approach is difficult is that you are trying to do things that should happen in the controller in the routes. Why not try this approach:

```
get 'android/:mode', :to => 'phone_views#android'
```

And in your controller:

```
class PhoneViewsController < ApplicationController
  def android
    self.send("android_#{params[:mode]")
  end

  def android_automated
    #Do Android Stuff
  end
  def android_interactive
    #Do Android Stuff
  end

end
```

Although such an approach may have some security issues when `params[:mode]` is not sanitized correctly (But I think the routing approach may have similar issues)

Comment: I had explored using a switch statement in the controller with a passed in param, in fact that was the first attempt but why complicate the controller logic when the routing engine should be doing this work. Imagine if I had a pre-existing controller and then marketing came down and said "We need to change all the urls for SEO purposes" should I have to change the controller or dynamically generate the route? This approach also suffers the missing template problem that the proc route does since it doesn't instantiate the correct view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
get 'android/:action', :controller => 'phone_views', :action => "android_#{:action}"
```

Comment: Error The action 'interactive' could not be found for PhoneViewsController since you named the variable :action it automatically associated it and ignores your declaration. If I rename the variable to mode ie: 
    android/:mode', :controller => 'phone_views', :action => "android_#{:mode}"
 the error changes to: The action 'android_mode' could not be found for PhoneViewsController